# WCF Callbacks services

Tags: wcf, callback

Just starting to look into WCF and came across the 
WSDualHttpBinding binding.

I have used .Net remoting in the past, but it was not possible to have callbacks to occur when the client was behind a router.
Callbacks only worked when 2 applications were running on a LAN.

As explained by this article.
http://blogs.msdn.com/manishg/archive/2004/10/16/243414.aspx

It mentions 
“If your client application is running behind a router (as in the case of most home networking setups), there is no way for the server to dispatch events to the client”

Does WCF find a way of rectifying this, I understand the binding TCP supports callbacks only works on a LAN? Am I right? It would good to have callbacks work across the Internet and was just wondering if this was possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not yet. The new relay bindings in WCF 4.0 rectify this for real, but the dual bindings are just a way to define server to client callbacks in a single contract.